# How to get the set of solutions of linear systems of inequations in Mathematica?

Tags: inequalities

I would like to solve the following system of equations:

$$y < -3 + 2x$$
$$y \ge 1-x$$
So I tried the following:

```
Solve[{y < -3 + 2 x, y >= 1 - x}, {x, y}]
```

But the following message appears: "**The solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information**"

I already plotted it and obtained the solution by the coordinates, but I want to get the specific result.

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica say to use reduce so use Reduce instead

```
Reduce[y < -3 + 2 x && y >= 1 - x]
```

Answer (score 5):

Amplifying on [cyrille.piatecki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38721/cyrille-piatecki)'s answer

```
Reduce[{y < -3 + 2 x, y >= 1 - x}, {x, y}]

(*  x > 4/3 && 1 - x <= y < -3 + 2 x  *)

Plot[{1 - x, 2 x - 3},
 {x, 4/3, 5},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]